# How to build 2d array in Java using recursion by giving a positive number?

Tags: java, recursion, multidimensional-array, java.util.scanner

I have a code that asks a user to enter a positive number.

Using recursion the system should display a 2d array like this:

If the user enter number 6

output:

0

1 0

2 1 0

3 2 1 0

4 3 2 1 0

5 4 3 2 1 0

This is my code:

```
package question1;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class PositiveNumber {

    public static void main(String[] args){

        int  n = 0;
        List<Integer>listofNumbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Choose a positive number");
        for(int i = 0 ; i< listofNumbers.size(); i++){
            listofNumbers.add(i);
             n = sc.nextInt();
            printInReverse(listofNumbers);
        }

    }

    public static void printInReverse(List<Integer>Listofnum){
        List temp = new ArrayList(Listofnum);
        Collections.reverse(temp);
        System.out.println(temp);
    }
}
```

It does not display any output. It just asks the user to choose a number.

Comment: Not going to post a solution.  But your problem is that at the beginning of the loop, `listofNumbers` is empty, so `listOfNumbers.size()` will be zero.  So the loop condition is false immediately, and the loop will never be entered.  I think you need to call `sc.nextInt()` before the loop, not inside it, and also make a few other changes.

Comment: Incidentally, you're not even TRYING to use recursion here.

Comment: what other changes ??

Comment: The changes that I would tell you about, if I really felt like doing somebody else's homework.

Comment: yes i know the first thing is to get the user input and display the output than i will try to change my code

Comment: ohhh i fixed i was not compare the i to the user input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the `n = sc.nextInt()` out of the for loop, and change the termination condition to `i < n`.

However, you don't need to build, copy and reverse the list - you can simply use another for loop.

Comment: The question is "how to build 2d array in java using recursion ...".  This is not an answer to that question.

Answer (score 0):

Your List is empty, so the condition in your FOR will always be 0.
You neeed to get the output before going in the array, or use a do-while